# How to get a grip on finance?

Tags: accounting, economics, business, statistics

I hope this is not too off-topic (theoretical but not necessarily off-topic), but I am just starting to understand the financial world and I am a bit confused while reading publications and books about this topic. I would like to build my understanding about it in a systematic way so I can gradually gather relevant information. I specialized in Mathematics and this is a perk that helps me grasp easier notions used in Economics, Statistics, Finance or Accounting. I am also reading lecture notes from relevant courses in the earlier mentioned subjects and I am studying Statistics which is a useful tool in decision making based on underlying data. I want to start a business as well as to become a shareholder and to stay up-to-date with financial news. In order to make the question more concrete, what resources (books/newspapers etc.) should I start with? (Financial Times or Euromoney are examples of what I am trying to read but I feel that I need something lighter at first to be able to fully understand them)

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered in a Q&A format. Think of specific questions you have, then search on this forum and using search engines. If you can't find the answer to a specific question, then ask it here as a new question. [I suggest you take the tour](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with how to pose questions that will be answered succinctly.

Comment: I hope the last phrase makes it more specific so I can receive some suggestions.

Comment: Well, now you're asking for product recommendations, which is also not permitted. The question, as-is, is too opinion based and not open to a definitive Q&A style (able to have a single answer selected as the "best"). As Pete B. mentioned, this type of question has been asked a lot, so it may be closed as a duplicate anyways.

Comment: Take a look at the [on-topic list](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for some better ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is perfectly on topic, and probably has been asked and answered many times.  However, I cannot help myself.

Here are some basics however:

**Personal Finance is not only about math.**  As a guy who "took vector calculus just for fun", I have learned that superior math skills do not translate into superior net worth.  Personal finance is about 50% behavior.  Take a look at the housing crisis, car loans, or payday lenders and you will understand that the desire to be accepted by others often trumps the math surrounding a transaction.

**Outline your goals**  What is it that you want in life?  A pile of money or to retire early?  What does your business look like?  How much cash will you need?  Do you want to own a ton of rental properties?  How does all this happen (set intermediate goals).

**Then get on a budget**  A budget is a plan to spend your money in advance.  Stick to it.  From there you can see how much money you have to implement various goals.  Are your goals to aggressive?   This is really important as people have a tendency to spend more money then they have.  Often times when people receive a bonus at work, they spend that one bonus on two or three times over.  A budget will prevent this from happening.

**Get an Emergency Fund**  Without an emergency fund, you be subject to the financial whims of people involved in your own life and that of the broader marketplace.  Once you have one, you are free to invest with impunity and have less stress in a world that deals out plenty.  Bad things will happen to you financially, protect against them.

**The best first investments are simple:**  Invest in yourself.  Find a way to make a very healthy income with upward mobility.  Also get out and stay out of debt.  These things are not sexy, but they pay off in the long run.

**The next best investment is also simple:**  Index funds.  These become the bench mark for all other investments.  If you do not stand a good chance of beating the S&P 500 index fund, why bother?  Just dump the money in the fund and sleep well at night.

Comment: Regarding business, I want as much money and as early as possible. I don't think I will ever retire if I am lucky enough to have a successful business. How do I start learning about index funds? Is this related to online Forex trading? I am interested in that. Do you have any advice for me in this respect?

Comment: Forex trading is a losing game for fools, forget about it as well as all other get rich quick schemes.  Goals need to be specific with metrics and dates.  You may want to research goal setting.  Have you completed the other steps?  Do them first before investing.  Read the Total Money Makeover, then Bogle on Investing.

Comment: Is that necessarily a get rich quick scheme? I cannot say for sure, but some people I know claim to make some money out of it (a couple of hundreds of euros a month while spending several hours a day on it). Also on Investopedia states that the Forex market is the most powerful market that influences others such as stock markets or bond markets.